# Why does the following web scraping code not work in R?

Tags: css, r, web-scraping, xpath

I tried to scrape the table on this website: https://www.timeshighereducation.com/world-university-rankings/2021/world-ranking#!/page/0/length/100/sort_by/rank/sort_order/asc/cols/stats, using R. I have the following code:

```
url<-"https://www.timeshighereducation.com/world-university-rankings/2021/world-ranking#!/page/0/length/100/sort_by/rank/sort_order/asc/cols/stats"
table1=url%>%
    read_html()%>%
    html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="datatable-1"]')%>%
    html_table()%>%
    .[[1]]
table1
```

The output only includes the column names with 0 row of actual data. Did I do anything wrong?

I also try to scrape the the column of university names first, with the code:

```
url<-"https://www.timeshighereducation.com/world-university-rankings/2021/world-ranking#!/page/0/length/100/sort_by/rank/sort_order/asc/cols/stats"
name=url%>%
    read_html()%>%
    html_nodes('.ranking-institution-title')%>%
    html_text()
name
```

Again the output is empty, but I can't figure out why.
The CSS path is found using Chrome extension SelectorGadget, which works for other website.

Answer (score 0):

The data is loaded on the page in the form of json.

```
data <- jsonlite::fromJSON('https://www.timeshighereducation.com/sites/default/files/the_data_rankings/world_university_rankings_2021_0__fa224219a267a5b9c4287386a97c70ea.json')
table1 <- data$data
head(table1[1:5])

#  rank_order rank                                  name scores_overall scores_overall_rank
#1         10    1                  University of Oxford           95.6                  10
#2         20    2                   Stanford University           94.9                  20
#3         30    3                    Harvard University           94.8                  30
#4         40    4    California Institute of Technology           94.5                  40
#5         50    5 Massachusetts Institute of Technology           94.4                  50
#6         60    6               University of Cambridge           94.0                  60
```

You can keep only the columns that you need from `table1`.